# Возврат результата функции

Tags: c, строки, функции

Стоит задача написать программу, подсчитывающую количество слов в строке. Для подсчета написал отдельную функцию в отдельном файле. Подскажите, как из этой функции вернуть результат выполнения с помощью `return`?
Вот функция подсчета:

```
#define OUT 0
#define IN 1
int wordCount(char buf[])
{
    int flag = 0;// флаг состояний 
    int count = 0;//счетчик
    int i=0 ;
    while (buf[i])
    {
        if (buf[i] != ' '&& flag == OUT)
        {
            count++;
            flag = IN;//âîøëè â ñëîâî
        }
        else if (buf[i] == ' '&& flag == IN)
            flag = OUT;//âûøëè èç ñëîâà
        i++;
    }

    return ;
}
```

Главная функция

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>//for strlen
#include "task1.h"
#define OUT 0
#define IN 1
#define N 256
int main()
{
    char buf[N] = { 0 };//массив для ввода строки пользователем
    int flag = 0;// флаг состояний 
    int count = 0;//счетчик
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter words:>");
    fgets(buf, 512, stdin);// считывется строка 
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';// удаление \0

        printf("%d\n",wordCount(buf));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если я правильно понял, счетчик слов - `count`. Вот его и возвращайте:

```
return count;
```

Comment: Зачем же? У вас функция подсчитывает количество слов, так? Целочисленную величину (`int`), что совершенно корректно указано в объявлении функции как `int wordCount(...` - вы и возвращаете из нее целое число (которое потом опять же совершенно корректно используете: `printf("%d\n",wordCount(buf));`). Так что ничего в `buf` записывать не нужно.

Answer (score -2):

```
#define OUT 0
#define IN 1
int wordCount(char buf[])
{
    int flag = 0;// флаг состояний 
    int count = 0;//счетчик
    int i=0 ;
    while (buf[i])
    {
        if (buf[i] != ' '&& flag == OUT)
        {
            count++;
            flag = IN;//âîøëè â ñëîâî
        }
        else if (buf[i] == ' '&& flag == IN)
            flag = OUT;//âûøëè èç ñëîâà
        i++;
    }

    return count ;
}
```

Мне кажется функцию main стоит сделать void чем возвращать 0.

Comment: Ваше предложение не соответствует стандарту...